# Update doctrine entity with ArrayCollection field

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, arraycollection, symfony-3.1

I have problem with update entity with relations (one to many, many to one). I trying to add some new element to ArrayCollection when update, but nothing to do.
Here is my code of create and add relation:

```
$auctionPhoto = new AuctionPhoto();
$auctionPhoto->setAuction($auction);
$auctionPhoto->setPath($path);
$auction->getPhotos()->add($auctionPhoto);
```

All is running by doctrine entity listener (preUptade). The same code is do when I create entity (prePersist), but then is works fine.

I debug this and before persist I have in Auction object right relations, but nothing save to database.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you do `$auction->getPhotos()->add($auctionPhoto)` ?

You should have a method `addPhoto()` or `addAuctionPhoto()` in your `Auction` entity, and use it like this:

`$auction->addPhoto($auctionPhoto)` or  `$auction->addAuctionPhoto($auctionPhoto)`

**EDIT:**

Maybe your entity `Auction` is not the owner of the relation between the two entities, then you need to add `$auctionPhoto->setAuction($auction)`, or if it's ManyToMany relation, then add `$auctionPhoto->addAuction($auction)`

Comment: I don't have any. How should looks like this method?

Comment: inside the method, you should have `$this->photos->add($auctionPhoto)`. The difference with the two method is that `$auction->getPhotos()` return an array with the same values as photos, not the reference of you photos attribut

Comment: Next time, generate your entities with
`php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/YourEntity`

Doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters

Comment: I'm not sure. Before I tried to create new ArrayCollection, add photos to this and after that use setPhotos on Auction - and doesn't work.

Comment: You can run `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/YourEntity` and see what methods Symfony will create for you. You will have your current entity named `~YourEntity` and it will generate you a new entity file. Or maybe your entity `Auction` is not the owner of the relation between the two entities, they you need to add `$auctionPhoto->setAuction($auction)`, or if it's ManyToMany, do `$auctionPhoto->addAuction($auction)`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$auction->getPhotos()->add($auctionPhoto);` with `$auction->addPhoto($auctionPhoto);`.

In your `Auction` entity, define the new method

```
// Auction.php
public function addPhoto(AuctionPhoto $thePhoto)
{
    $this->photos[] = $thePhoto; // Add the photo to the object
    $thePhoto->setAuction($this); // AuctionPhoto entity need to know about the reference

    return $this; // Just for method chaining
}
```

(I assume `$photos` is your ArrayCollection which contains auction's photos)

Basically what you missed is to give a reference back to your entity:
`$thePhoto->setAuction($this);`

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying nothing is in the database before you run this:

```
$em->persist($auction);
$em->flush();
```

If so, that is correct functionality. You need to persist then flush, then data is stored.

Comment: No, this is not this. Other field of auction like title saved. And as I say, this is the same code as in create action but create works.